# How to add focus to textformfield which has validation error

Tags: flutter, validation, setfocus

I have textformfields in my form. When I click on submit button the validation error displays under the textformfield. I want to add focus to that particular field so when user clicks on save button the field pops up. user should not need to scroll up and type the info. User should be able to directly start typing. In current scenario user gets confused and is unaware of why save button didnt work. Bcoz until scrolled up the error is unknown.

```
 TextFormField(
                  controller: NoteController,
                   validator: (String value){
                    if(value.isEmpty)
                      {
                        return "Note can't be null";
                      }
                    else
                      return null;
                   },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 2.0),)),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  minLines: 5,
                  maxLines: 5, 
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.note.note = value;
                  },

                ),

bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = globalFormKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

void _save() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using FocusNode and TextField. you can read more about it here
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus

Let me show you an example (Tried it and it works):

Before the build method:

```
  final FocusNode noteFocus = FocusNode();
```

In the build method:

```
 Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              // Add FocusNode to TextFieldForm
              focusNode: noteFocus,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  // Request focus in case of error
                  noteFocus.requestFocus();
                  return "Note can't be null";
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  print('Validated');
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: But using this how to set focus for the field which is showing error

Comment: I added an example to show you  :) @FathimaShafana

Comment: No its not working. the textfield is not receiving focus.

Comment: How to do the same when there are multiple textformfield?

Answer (score 0):

Use FocusNode like this.

```
FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

TextFormField(
                  controller: NoteController,
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                   validator: (String value){
                    if(value.isEmpty)
                      {
                        Focus.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
                        return "Note can't be null";
                      }
                    else
                      return null;
                   },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 2.0),)),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  minLines: 5,
                  maxLines: 5, 
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.note.note = value;
                  },

                ),
```

Comment: It didn't  work. The focus didnt shift to the textformfield which had error

Comment: Focus.of() was called with a context that does not contain a Focus between the given context and the nearest FocusScope widget. Moreover validation error also were not shown

Answer (score 0):

This is my whole implementation who does precisely that. The best part is that it sets the focus **always** in the first Input (TextFormField) which contains errors after executing the validators. What decides the order is a previously given 'index' key inside a Map<String, dynamic>.

*AuthScreen*

```
import 'package:flutter_267_chat/flutter_resources.dart';
import 'package:flutter_267_chat/external_resources.dart';
import 'package:flutter_267_chat/custom_resources.dart';

final _firebase = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool isSignup;

  const AuthScreen({super.key, this.title = 'Chatty', this.isSignup = true});

  @override
  State<AuthScreen> createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  bool _isLogin = true;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _isAuthenticating = false;

  var _enteredEmail = '';
  var _enteredUsername = '';
  var _enteredPassword = '';
  File? _selectedImageFile;
  String imageError = '';

  FocusNode focusNodeEmail = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNodeUsername = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNodePassword = FocusNode();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes = [];

  void onPickImage(File? aImage) => _selectedImageFile = aImage;

  void toggleAuth() => setState(() => _isLogin = !_isLogin);

  void _logIn() async {
    setState(() => _isAuthenticating = true);
    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential = await _firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _enteredEmail, password: _enteredPassword);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      if (mounted) {
        String? errorMessage;
        if (error.code == 'INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS') {
          errorMessage = 'Invalid login credentials';
        }
        NotificationsHelper.showSnackBarMessage(context, errorMessage ?? error.message ?? 'Authentication failed');
      }
    }
    if (mounted) setState(() => _isAuthenticating = false);
  }

  void _signUp() async {
    setState(() => _isAuthenticating = true);
    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential = await _firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _enteredEmail, password: _enteredPassword);
      final String userImageFileName = '${userCredential.user!.uid}.jpg';
      final Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('user_images').child(userImageFileName);
      await storageReference.putFile(_selectedImageFile!);
      final String uploadedImageUrl = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();

      final DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> userReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user!.uid);
      final Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
        'username': _enteredUsername,
        'email': userCredential.user!.email,
        'image_url': uploadedImageUrl,
      };
      await userReference.set(userData);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      if (mounted) {
        if (error.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
          //
        }
        NotificationsHelper.showSnackBarMessage(context, error.message ?? 'Authentication failed');
      }
    }

    if (mounted) setState(() => _isAuthenticating = false);
  }

  void focusInputsWithErrors() {
    if (inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.isNotEmpty) {
      inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.sort((a, b) => (b['index']).compareTo(a['index']));
      inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes = inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.reversed.toList();
      final Map<String, dynamic> firstInputFocusNodeMap = inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.first;
      final FocusNode firstInputFocusNode = firstInputFocusNodeMap['node'];
      firstInputFocusNode.requestFocus();
    }
  }

  void _submit() async {
    inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.clear();
    setState(() => imageError = _selectedImageFile == null ? 'Must pick a picture' : '');

    final bool formIsValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    final bool signUpImageIsNull = !_isLogin && _selectedImageFile == null;
    if (!formIsValid || signUpImageIsNull) {
      focusInputsWithErrors();
      return;
    }

    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    _isLogin ? _logIn() : _signUp();

    if (!context.mounted) return;
  }

  void _resetForm() {
    setState(() => imageError = '');
    _formKey.currentState!.reset();
    inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final TextTheme textTheme = themeData.textTheme;
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = themeData.colorScheme;
    final emailFocusNodeMap = {'node': focusNodeEmail, 'index': 1};
    final usernameFocusNodeMap = {'node': focusNodeUsername, 'index': 2};
    final passwordFocusNodeMap = {'node': focusNodePassword, 'index': 3};

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      backgroundColor: colorScheme.primary,
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              // Logo
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                width: 140,
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/chat.png'),
              ),

              // Auth Card with the form
              Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            // User Image Picker
                            // if (!_isLogin) UserImagePicker(onPickImage: (d) {}),
                            AnimatedSwitcher(
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              // reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              child: !_isLogin
                                  ? Column(
                                      children: [
                                        UserImagePicker(onPickImage: onPickImage),
                                        SizedBox(height: 8),
                                        // Image Error
                                        Text(imageError, style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFBA1A1A))),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  : null,
                            ),

                            // Email Input
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email address', helperText: ' '),
                              focusNode: focusNodeEmail,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              autocorrect: false,
                              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                              validator: (String? value) {
                                if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                                  inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(emailFocusNodeMap);
                                  return 'The email can not be blank';
                                }
                                final bool isValidEmail = EmailValidator.validate(value);
                                if (!isValidEmail) {
                                  inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(emailFocusNodeMap);
                                  return 'The email must be valid';
                                }

                                return null;
                              },
                              onSaved: (String? value) {
                                _enteredEmail = value!.trim();
                              },
                              onFieldSubmitted: (String? value) => _submit(),
                            ),

                            // Username Input
                            AnimatedSwitcher(
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              // reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 900),
                              child: !_isLogin
                                  ? TextFormField(
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username', helperText: ' '),
                                      enableSuggestions: false,
                                      focusNode: focusNodeUsername,
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                                      // autocorrect: false,
                                      validator: (String? value) {
                                        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                                          inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(usernameFocusNodeMap);

                                          return 'The username can not be blank';
                                        }
                                        if (value.trim().length < 3) {
                                          inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(usernameFocusNodeMap);

                                          return 'The username must be at least 3 characters long';
                                        }

                                        return null;
                                      },
                                      onSaved: (String? value) {
                                        _enteredUsername = value!;
                                      },
                                      onFieldSubmitted: (String? value) => _submit(),
                                    )
                                  : null,
                            ),

                            // Password Input
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password', helperText: ' '),
                              focusNode: focusNodePassword,
                              // autocorrect: false,
                              obscureText: true,
                              obscuringCharacter: '*',
                              validator: (String? value) {
                                if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                                  inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(passwordFocusNodeMap);

                                  return 'The password can not be blank';
                                }
                                if (value.trim().length < 6) {
                                  inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(passwordFocusNodeMap);
                                  return 'The password must be at least 6 characters long';
                                }

                                return null;
                              },
                              onSaved: (String? value) {
                                _enteredPassword = value!;
                              },
                              onFieldSubmitted: (String? value) => _submit(),
                            ),

                            // SizedBox(height: 12),

                            Stack(
                              children: [
                                // Submit & Reset buttons
                                Opacity(
                                  opacity: _isAuthenticating ? 0 : 1,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      // Submit button
                                      ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: _submit,
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: colorScheme.primaryContainer),
                                        child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Log in' : 'Create account'),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 12),
                                      // Reset button
                                      ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: _resetForm,
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: colorScheme.primaryContainer),
                                        child: Text('Reset'),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),

                                if (_isAuthenticating)
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                              ],
                            ),

                            // SizedBox(height: 12),

                            // Auth Toggling button
                            Opacity(
                              opacity: _isAuthenticating ? 0 : 1,
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: toggleAuth,
                                child: Text(
                                  _isLogin ? 'No account? Sign up' : 'Have an account? Log in',
                                  style: textTheme.labelSmall,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example we have three TextFormField(s) (email, username and password). The important steps are the following.

**Step 1:** Declare the variables inside the StatefulWidget State class.

```
  FocusNode focusNodeEmail = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNodeUsername = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNodePassword = FocusNode();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes = [];
```

**Step 2:** We declare now inside the build method, the Map<String, dynamic> for each Input, which will later be inserted inside the List.

```
final emailFocusNodeMap = {'node': focusNodeEmail, 'index': 1};
final usernameFocusNodeMap = {'node': focusNodeUsername, 'index': 2};
final passwordFocusNodeMap = {'node': focusNodePassword, 'index': 3};
```

**Step 3:** Link each FocusNode with its respective TextFormField and trigger the filling in validation.

```
                    // Email Input
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email address', helperText: ' '),
                      focusNode: focusNodeEmail,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      autocorrect: false,
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                      validator: (String? value) {
                        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                          inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(emailFocusNodeMap);
                          return 'The email can not be blank';
                        }
                        final bool isValidEmail = EmailValidator.validate(value);
                        if (!isValidEmail) {
                          inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(emailFocusNodeMap);
                          return 'The email must be valid';
                        }

                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (String? value) {
                        _enteredEmail = value!.trim();
                      },
                      onFieldSubmitted: (String? value) => _submit(),
                    ),

                    // Username Input
                    AnimatedSwitcher(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      // reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 900),
                      child: !_isLogin
                          ? TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username', helperText: ' '),
                              enableSuggestions: false,
                              focusNode: focusNodeUsername,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                              // autocorrect: false,
                              validator: (String? value) {
                                if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                                  inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(usernameFocusNodeMap);

                                  return 'The username can not be blank';
                                }
                                if (value.trim().length < 3) {
                                  inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(usernameFocusNodeMap);

                                  return 'The username must be at least 3 characters long';
                                }

                                return null;
                              },
                              onSaved: (String? value) {
                                _enteredUsername = value!;
                              },
                              onFieldSubmitted: (String? value) => _submit(),
                            )
                          : null,
                    ),

                    // Password Input
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password', helperText: ' '),
                      focusNode: focusNodePassword,
                      // autocorrect: false,
                      obscureText: true,
                      obscuringCharacter: '*',
                      validator: (String? value) {
                        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                          inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(passwordFocusNodeMap);

                          return 'The password can not be blank';
                        }
                        if (value.trim().length < 6) {
                          inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.add(passwordFocusNodeMap);
                          return 'The password must be at least 6 characters long';
                        }

                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (String? value) {
                        _enteredPassword = value!;
                      },
                      onFieldSubmitted: (String? value) => _submit(),
                    ),
```

**Step 4:** When calling submit, we must empty the existing List first, and only then we can validate.

```
  void _submit() async {
    inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.clear();
    setState(() => imageError = _selectedImageFile == null ? 'Must pick a picture' : '');

    final bool formIsValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    final bool signUpImageIsNull = !_isLogin && _selectedImageFile == null;
    if (!formIsValid || signUpImageIsNull) {
      focusInputsWithErrors();
      return;
    }

    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    _isLogin ? _logIn() : _signUp();

    if (!context.mounted) return;
  }
```

**Step 5:** Here is where the sorting, reversal and then focusing happens.

```
  void focusInputsWithErrors() {
    if (inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.isNotEmpty) {
      inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.sort((a, b) => (b['index']).compareTo(a['index']));
      inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes = inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.reversed.toList();
      final Map<String, dynamic> firstInputFocusNodeMap = inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.first;
      final FocusNode firstInputFocusNode = firstInputFocusNodeMap['node'];
      firstInputFocusNode.requestFocus();
    }
  }
```

**Step 6:** And of course, we must clear the List of Maps also in reset.

```
  void _resetForm() {
    setState(() => imageError = '');
    _formKey.currentState!.reset();
    inputsWithErrorsFocusNodes.clear();
  }
```

**Visual Result:**

[image]